# Miniconda only installs partially how can I find the error?

Tags: python, windows, installation, conda, miniconda

[image: Miniconda structure after install on Windows 10]

This is how it looks like when I install Miniconda on Windows 10 - how can I debug this?
Is there an installation log or something?
I followed this instructions here: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/silent-mode/

EDIT 1: The exact version of the executable is Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Windows-x86_64.exe from https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/.

EDIT 2: I stumbled over this post: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11761/how-to-analyze-deeply-every-single-step-of-a-windows-executable-installer/11762#11762?newreg=f273c3b5cf524ca3a15ea3154db39b34. Would the answer for this post also apply to my Miniconda installation scenario or would the proposed tools not be of value?

Comment: Why use conda to being with? [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) is PEP compliant contrary to conda. I am aware that many workflows still require conda. Companies with short term resources should consider the switch for the stability poetry-based development provides. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have miniconda but none of the packages. See this page to download the additional packages and then maybe it will work.

https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

Comment: Good point, Anthony. Certainly something I need to check next week with the Software Delivery Team. Indeed `start /wait "" Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe /InstallationType=JustMe /RegisterPython=0 /S /D=%UserProfile%\Miniconda3` has as prerequisite that the .exe file exists. On the other hand, for some people the installation works, so a kind of log file - if it could be generated - would be really helpful. To see why it only works for some of the people.

Comment: Is their maybe a difference of PCs, I assume not but maybe some are using a 32 bit version and some a 64 bit version and therefore the software isn't working with some.

Comment: All of them are 64-bit. And all of them get the same executable. To be precise: Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Windows-x86_64.exe from https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/.

Comment: This person seemed to have a similar problem  https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/3204      He deleted the miniconda folder and then removed all registry entries that had "orange" and/or "miniconda" in them. Then he tried the original exe file, and the installation was completed.

Comment: But how did he get to the error message? And yes, the policy is that the people first have to remove all previous conda and python installations as well as the environment variables that reference conda and Python. Still even for new laptops, the problem occurs.

Comment: I think your best bet is to contact anaconda (https://www.anaconda.com/contact) because this problem is clearly is a bug because all the conditions are right and some of the devices are installing it so either there's a major bug or a little detail that affects it. If its a little detail then anaconda should know about it.